# Wordpress to be used more like an app?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

Maybe a little bit hard question...

As life is changing, emails are not used any more in nowdays phone delivery apps, so I have a Pizza delivery store built on wordpress with disabled email field and I have mobile number with OTP instead.

I mean that I have completely disabled email field from registration/checkout page and I have only phone number and name, surname, address.

Everything was working great, but now I noticed that customers are not grouped any more, I mean that on every different order, same customer is duplicated and same customers have different orders, but actually they are the same :(

Any idea will be helpful, how to change phone field to be the main one for woocommerce?

(On screenshot this is same customer, but woo thinks its a different one as there is no email :( cuatomer has no username as these are all guest orders)

[image]

Comment: While anything is possible, this is not a quick or simple task. If you prefer to spend your time running the business, this WooCommerce extension that might serve as a workaround for you: https://woocommerce.com/products/registration-login-with-mobile-phone-number/ 
However, it requires your customers to register for an account, rather than checking out as a guest. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @nightowl thanks for the answer but I already have similar plugin set up and running. I don't want to make users register, that's my problem...